# How to define elements in a DTD which share the declaration?

Tags: xml, validation, dtd

How can I define elements in a DTD which share the same declaration?

I tried this which leads to a syntax error:

```
<!ELEMENT (expression|condition) (code-text+)>
```

Where expression and condition have the same declaration, that means the same sub-elements and attributes.

Comment: You can't do that with DTDs, they're not expressive enough. That's why DTD is obsolete, and most use XML Schema instead.

Comment: I though about using XSD but they are very horrible to write. I would get a very large file which I hoped to get around :-(

Comment: Could I somehow use an Entity to "copy" the declaration?

Comment: you accepted (thanks) but didn't upvote (not necessary of course) perhaps there's something unclear? Could you comment so that I can expand my answer to make it more understandable for you and future visitors?

Comment: On *"You can't do that with DTDs"* >> why not? see my example. And DTD is not obsolete. We all use XML and the DTD is an indissolubly part of the XML spec. Of course, XSD, RelaxNG, Schematron and the likes are much better in describing XML structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Side note: In principle I would agree with using XSD instead of DTD (alternatively, use [RelaxNG](http://www.relaxng.org/), which is a good, standardized alternative to XSD and much briefer plus much easier to understand and read). Don't worry too much about the extended code. It is quite easy to read and gives you a strong expressive power. Instead of being blocked by the technology, it will help you build what you need. IDEs like Visual Studio, Eclipse and others have graphical design tools for building your model which makes creating XSDs a breeze.)*

But that doesn't answer your question. It is quite easy to reuse a definition in a DTD. Look at the [HTML DTD](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/sgml/dtd.html#coreattrs)s, it happens all the time. The key is to use parameter entities. Here's a simple example:

```
<!-- the "model" -->
<!ENTITY % commoncontent
    "content | xxx">
<!ENTITY % commonattrs
    "att1  CDATA  #IMPLIED
     att2  CDATA  #IMPLIED">

<!-- elements -->
<!ELEMENT root ANY>
<!ELEMENT content ANY>
<!ELEMENT xxx EMPTY>

<!-- elements that share the same model -->
<!ELEMENT hello  (%commoncontent;)+>
<!ELEMENT world  (%commoncontent;)+>

<!-- adding the attributes to the elements with the same model -->
<!ATTLIST hello %commonattrs;>
<!ATTLIST world %commonattrs;>
```

which basically makes `hello` and `world` elements contain exactly the same set of attributes and content. I used a definition of non-mandatory and unordered elements as content, which makes the following XML document valid with the above DTD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE root SYSTEM "multipleSharedDefinitions.dtd">
<root>
    <hello att1="bla">            
        <content />
    </hello>
    <world att1="bla" att2="blabla">
        <content />
        <xxx />
    </world>
</root>
```